# C# Event Log EntryWrittenEventHandler loads not just last event

Tags: c#, event-log

I have created a little program (service or console, tested both with same result) to watch the Windows Security Event log for certain events id's only, and then perform an action on THE LAST EVENT with this id coming through.

This works OK for a while and then suddenly, a few times a day, the program goes and gets ALL events with those specified event id's in the entire log (instead of just the last one).

Here is my code:

```
class Program
{   // These are the events I want to listen to
    public static string[] eventsToListen = { "4727", "4730", "5136", "5139" };

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        EventLog eventLog = new EventLog("Security", Environment.MachineName);

        eventLog.EntryWritten += new EntryWrittenEventHandler(OnEntryWrittenAsync);
        eventLog.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void OnEntryWrittenAsync(object sender, EntryWrittenEventArgs e)
    {
        if (eventsToListen.Contains(e.Entry.InstanceId.ToString()))
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => writeToRemoteLog(e.Entry));
        }
    }

    private static void writeToRemoteLog(EventLogEntry entry)
    {
        string logMessage = null;

        if (EventLog.Exists("DCGroupEvents", "targetMachineName"))
        {
            try
            {
                var log = new EventLog("DCGroupEvents", "targetMachineName");
                log.Source = "DCGroupEvents";
                String strMessage = entry.Index.ToString();
                log.WriteEntry(strMessage);
                log.Close();
                logMessage = entry.InstanceId.ToString() + "/" + entry.TimeWritten.ToString() + "/" + entry.Index.ToString() + " written to eventlog";
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                logMessage = e.Message;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            logMessage = "Log does not exist";
        }
        Console.WriteLine(logMessage);
        logMessage = null;

    }
}
```

How can I avoid this download of ALL events (meeting the criteria) several times a day?

Many thanks in advance for anyone who knows this, I am a bit stuck at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

> The system responds to WriteEntry only if the last write event occurred at least six seconds previously. This implies you will only receive one EntryWritten event notification within a six-second interval, even if more than one event log change occurs. If you insert a sufficiently long sleep interval (around 10 seconds) between calls to WriteEntry, you are less likely to miss an event. However, if write events occur more frequently, you might not recieve the event notification until the next interval. Typically, missed event notifications are not lost, but delayed.

source: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b0314be2-3b75-4a21-aabc-4777cd8ba100/eventlogentrywritten-firing-for-events-in-the-past?forum=netfxbcl

Comment: Thanks! Will try this. Do I put the thread.sleep inside OnEntryWrittenAsync or inside the function that it calls (writeToRemoteLog). I see in the link they put it in their OnEntryWritten and elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

Although not the ideal solution, you can try and use a mapping table to solve the problem by implementing a dictionary that stores the event properties and index id of the event. Create a method that would validate and update the mapping table and return a boolean result. Then instead of performing the activity when the event is fired, perform a validation by calling the ValidatedUpdate(params) and based on the result perform the activity. The ValidatedUpdate(params) method checks 1; if the event was written on the current day 2; if the index id already exists in the mapping table 3; if the event id is the same as what you need to filter.

When these conditions match then only it is determined to be a "new" event for that day. The entry is then added to the dictionary and a boolean result can be returned for future tracking. In order to reduce the bloat a timer can be implemented that will "clean" the mapping table on a daily basis by flushing the values. Something like the below

```
    private ConcurrentDictionary<int, DateTime> mappingTable;

    private bool ValidateAndUpdate(int id, DateTime entry)
    {
        try
        {
            if(!mappingTable.ContainsKey(id) && entry.TimeStamp > DateTime.Today.Date)
            {
                mappingTable.TryAdd(id, entry);

                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception exception)
        {
            //handle exception event
        }
    }

    private void OnEntryWritten(object sender, EntryWrittenEventArgs e)
    {
        //preceding code here

        if(ValidateAndUpdate(e.Entry.Index, entry) == true)
        {
            //perform operation
        }
        catch(Exception exception)
        {
            //handle exception event
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I am going to try this! I have had to shelve this as I just could not solve it, or reproduce the behaviour for that matter. Will keep you posted.

Comment: updated the comment to provide an example of how I solved this problem. The only other thing I did was use a clean up timer to ensure the table never stores entries longer than a day in the past. This has worked for me and have run such implementation in production for a long period without any issues or even performance issues

Comment: I have implemented this, thanks again!, and will know once it has run for a while whether the issue (of a bunch of OLD events gets taken suddenly after a week or so) is solved . I did modify it somewhat, in that I passed the entire event into the ValidateAndUpdate function as I had a number of parameters to check on. I also wonder if the date is necessary in the dictionary, as in fact we are really only using the keys (the event date is compared to today). Is there any reason you use the date in your dictionary ?